# SQLite Insert Values If Value Does Not Exist

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert

How do you avoid adding duplicate entries in SQLite when inserting values?

Right now when I insert, it is adding duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a unique index somewhere on the table to you're inserting rows into:

```
create unique index mytable_id on mytable (id)
```

Now if you try to add two rows with the same id to mytable an error will be raised by sqlite.